# How to reference 3rd party assemblies without copying them locally?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, assemblies, runtime

I'm working with a lot of 3rd party assemblies that are installed by default with the SDKs. When using Reflection however, .NET crashes with the following error **"Could not load file or assembly [Name.dll]"**. So I've found there are 3 solutions:

- Turn "local copy" On, which forces the compiler to copy all assemblies to the build folder (dramatically increasing the filesize)
- Compile directly into the 3rd party Program Files folder, letting the .NET runtime easily find the assemblies (since they're in the same folder). This makes it more difficult to manage the installation, having 2 applications share a common folder.
- Add most of the 3rd party assemblies into the GAC (using gacutil) and reference it using its strong name. But this triggers another kind of "File not found" error, probably the assembly cannot function purely from the GAC since it needs some files from its native Program Files directory.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to hint the 3rd party assembly directory path to the .NET runtime, so I can compile my app elsewhere, and not be forced to carry around the baggage of 3rd party assemblies. (They would already be installed on the end-user computers)

Comment: couldn't those assemblies be GAC'd on a Server or Machine, or could you create a .MSI Installer for your application and introduce versioning perhaps..? just an idea..

Comment: glad that I was able to quickly help you on that.. VOTEUP ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the assemblies are currently in a separate 'shared' directory, this implies that they could be versioned independently from the program that references them.  "Copy Local" is preferable to that here, as otherwise you could wind up in the old "DLL hell" of incompatible versions swapped out without your knowledge.

The GAC is meant to address this problem, though then of course you need to use strong-naming and you need all of the assemblies they reference to be strong-named and go in the GAC as well.  This creates additional work to manage the versioning and installation, but it does allow for parallel versioning and prevents duplication.  Still, if you only reference an assembly from a few applications, putting it in the GAC is probably overkill.  You might actually end up taking up more disk space in the long run due to an accumulation of versions during updates, whereas Copy Local only leaves you with one version per application loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't those assemblies be GAC'd on a Server or Machine, 
or could you create a .MSI Installer for your application and introduce versioning perhaps..? just an idea.

Comment: This helped, but I'm currently resorting to #2 to make it work. Your solution (#3) does not ... see the post for reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If the assemblies are in a network folder, then .NET default security will not load them. You need to adjust the security settings under .NET configuration control panel, under "Runtime Security Policy" there is wizard to "Adjust Zone Security" and then pick "Local Internet" with "Full Trust".

[image: .NET Security Adjust]